# Replacing a line in a text file with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a few bash variables and I want to replace some lines in a text file I have with 
only the values of these variables.

To give an artificial example.

Say I have a file named test (The numbers indicate line numbers and not text within the file.)

1. Mary
2. Had
3. A Little
4. Lamb

I want to replace line number 3 with the line `45 56`. In my bash file I have stored
XL=45 and XU=56 and I tried

```
XL=45
XU=56
sed -i '3s/.*/ $XL $XU/' test
```

However this replaces the third line with $XL and $XU and not their actual values. 
How do I do this?

I know the obvious solution would be to replace $XL and $XU in the sed command with 
the actual values, but I want to replace many such lines in my long text file . So I want to define the XL and XU as variables at the top so I dont have to change my values everywhere.

Answer (score 6):

Use double quotes:

```
sed -i "3s/.*/ $XL $XU/" test
```

Single quotes prevent variable expansion.

Answer (score 5):

An `awk` version

```
$ cat file
Mary
Had
A Little
Lamb

$ awk 'NR==3 {$0=l}1' l="$XL $XU" file
Mary
Had
45 56
Lamb
```

Comment: +1 for not allowing code injection.